# Double positive x-axes plot

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to draw a plot in which the coordinate system is split in two: the y-axis in the middle running from 1e0 (it's a loglog plot) and two x-axes running from the same 1e0 to positive values 1e3.

I hope this horrible sketch could help:
[image: Sketch]

How can I realize this plot?

Comment: What is the data to be plotted ?

Comment: @percusse you're right,  should write: it's a set of pairs of values from numerics.

Comment: Check the manual for axis on bottom, axis lines=left and axis lines=right (p259) x dir=reverse (p272) and groupplots (p390).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[name=first,domain=1:1000,axis lines=left,
          enlargelimits=0.2,log ticks with fixed point,xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
          ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south,rotate=-90},
          xlabel style={at={(1,0)}, anchor=west},
        ]
      \addplot[only marks] {rand};
    \end{loglogaxis}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[at={(first.south west)},
           anchor=south east,hide y axis,domain=1:1000,axis x line=bottom,x dir=reverse,
          enlargelimits=0.2,log ticks with fixed point,xlabel={$x$},
          xlabel style={at={(0,0)}, anchor=east},
        ]
      \addplot[only marks] {rand};
    \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being hugely late, however that worked fine. Thanks.